# Encrypted partition for sharing files between Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, encryption

I recently got a new laptop with one SSD one HDD. I intend to setup a dual-boot with Windows and Ubuntu by splitting the SSD in half. However, I would also like to use the HDD or at least a part of it as a storage that both operating systems could use.

What tools should I use? I suppose NTFS is still the only file system that's supported by both, but can I expect it to work with Ubuntu without problems? And now that TrueCrypt has been discontinued, what should I use for encryption?

Comment: Try Veracrypt. Its a fork of Truecrypt and actively developed.

Comment: It also has a ppa: `ppa:unit193/encryption`

Answer (score 0):

Veracrypt

Ext (Linux)is also supported when using ext2fsd

Comment: How reliably does ext2fsd work? (The home page has a pretty stern warning.) Is it better to use that or NTFS?

Comment: For me it works ok(unless you want to install visual studio on Windows)